# Field name same as field type using unnamed namespace

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider this sample of code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace /* unnamed namespace */
{
    struct Foo
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    };
}

struct Boo
{
    Foo Foo; /* field name same as field type */
    int c;
    void print();
};

void Boo::print()
{
    std::cout<<"c = "<<c<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Foo "<<Foo.a<<" "<<Foo.b<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    Boo boo;
    boo.c=30;
    boo.Foo.a=-21;
    boo.Foo.b=98;
    boo.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Clang can compile it without errors.

Debian clang version 3.5.0-9 (tags/RELEASE_350/final) (based on LLVM 3.5.0)

Microsoft cl.exe compile it without errors. (I don't remember version. I use VS 2012)

And GCC: gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10):

```
main.cpp:14:6: error: declaration of ‘{anonymous}::Foo Boo::Foo [-fpermissive]
  Foo Foo; /* field name same as field type */
      ^
main.cpp:5:9: error: changes meaning of ‘Foo’ from ‘struct {anonymous}::Foo’[-fpermissive]
  struct Foo
         ^
```

What is good behavior of compiler? Why GCC can't compile it, but clang and cl.exe does? What C++ standard says?

Answer (score 4):

Both are correct. Per §3.3.7/1

> The following rules describe the scope of names declared in classes.
>
> 1. [..]
> 2. A name `N` used in a class `S` shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of `S`. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

Neither are obligated to give an error, gcc chose to and clang apparently chose not to. It's conforming either way.

Comment: The classic C++ case where everybody is [technically correct](http://i.imgur.com/fXn6hd5.jpg) even though everybody does something different. :)

Comment: Maybe i don't know something about clang. If struct Foo will be declared in global namespace (without unnamed namespace) clang still compile it and gcc can't. (WTF???) I can't check cl.exe...

Comment: @MichałSzczepaniak There's really no difference w.r.t. this rule between the global namespace and an unnamed one.

Comment: @MichałSzczepaniak: Anything can happen. The behaviour you see will be somehow related to the deep internals of how the two different compilers do their job but, ultimately, you shouldn't care about it because the code is ill-formed either way.